# In philosophy, why are feminism and transsexuality so controversial?

Tags: feminism, philosophy-of-sexuality, transsexuality, equality

Is it possible for feminism and transsexuality to be discussed philosophically? Is this hindered by the domination of philosophy by males?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150076/discussion-on-question-by-meanach-in-philosophy-why-are-feminism-and-transsexua); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there is a lot of work done on the philosophy of gender that doesn't have a political focus and doesn't devolve into meaningless political debate. This is mostly in actual academic philosophical work. General discussion on the internet though doesn't lend itself to impartial and respectful debate. People will get heated over the interpretation of Descartes on the best of days, so you can imagine how something as loaded as gender issues gets treated outside (and inside, even) an academic context.

Additionally, I don't really see a problem with feminism and gender philosophy being overly political, because the issues and harms women and transgender people face are as political as you can get. It would be nice if this wasn't the case, but unfortunately marginalised groups are almost forced to exist in a political context. To fix the issue of the politicisation of identity you also have to look at it in a political context. The more you separate the two the further away from the real world issues you get. Which is fine for some things but not for others.

As others have pointed out too, most new developments in philosophy are almost always controversial. Critique is a major part of what philosophy is, so anything new that gets published is bound to get at least a little pushback.

There is something to be said sociologically about why there is so much division and vitriol over certain politicised issues, but this is philosophy so I'd ask somewhere else for more on that.

Comment: Can you cite some of this work?

Comment: @user253751 Try Judith Butler, or maybe this SEP article on feminist perspectives on gender, plenty of resources here for proper philosophy on gender https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminism-gender/.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think gender is more controversial than any other topic. Philosophy tends to be controversial by nature. Collingwood said that we are "ticklish" about our metaphysics. As for avoiding politics, why would you even try? Feminism is primarily a political movement. Why would anyone even think of treating it as non-political?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149982/discussion-on-answer-by-olivier5-in-philosophy-why-are-feminism-and-transsexual); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

First, some side notes:

#### This is philosophy, not politics

As I pointed out in the question you're probably referring to, these topics are political, and this is a philosophy site. I would've said the same thing if this question had been posted on the programming or workplace site: it's a question about politics, it doesn't belong on this site. We have [a politics site](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) that seems far better suited for such questions (although I can't comment on what's appropriate on that site).

Plenty of questions about trans people should also be on topic on a biology, psychology or neuroscience site. That still isn't philosophy.

Despite how some people treat it, philosophy is not a catch-all for any scientific topic, any political topic, or just anything you wonder about generally.

That's not to say *no* question about those topics would be about philosophy. It's just to say that those topics aren't inherently philosophical.

Much of this question and the answers (including this answer) is arguably still about politics instead of philosophy.

#### "Political ideology"?

On the note of "political ideology", many people are way too keen to dismiss things as "just politics" or "primarily a political movement", or try to take the political element out of the discussion. But the obvious response is: what do you think politics is?

Politics is about what rights we give people, what laws we make, etc. Feminism and trans activism is primarily about what rights we give people. So to discuss those things "without politics" makes no sense.

And if you don't think politics is important, you presumably also wouldn't have cared about *political* movements to abolish slavery, and whether it's legal to own other human beings. What people presumably try to imply by calling something "just politics" is that they don't consider a movement to be of any consequence, yet they aren't bothered enough to try to explain why (or to explain why the reasons people give for why it's important, e.g. people are dying, isn't reason enough for them to care).

#### "Transgenderism"?

"Transgenderism" is also [a derogatory term](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgbt/comments/16fgeid/question_but_is_the_term_transgenderism_offensive/).

> "Transgenderism" makes it sound like an ideology - something you believe or choose to follow - or a disease. Technically, it is a condition in the same way that being tall is a condition, but nobody says "tall-ism".

This is well in line with the anti-trans narrative that being trans is not actually a thing (despite all the science that says it is), and trans people wouldn't exist if the idea weren't spread through society (despite all the people who figured out that they were trans long before they heard about it).

There isn't an exact replacement for "transgenderism", as that's used as an all-encompassing term for anything related to trans people. "Gender" also doesn't have the equivalent form that "sexuality" is for "sex", to turn it into a noun. But some use "transgender" itself as an equivalent noun, to refer to being trans, although one shouldn't describe someone as "a transgender".

But one or more of the following terms could work, depending on what you're talking about: pro-trans views, trans-affirming views, trans-affirming science, the existence of trans people, trans activism, pro-trans people, or trans people. ["Transness"](https://www.reddit.com/r/asktransgender/comments/a367xi/what_are_your_thoughts_on_the_word_transness_and/) could work too to describe the state of being trans, but that hasn't really caught on.

GLAAD has [a page on terminology](https://glaad.org/reference/trans-terms/) (that also mentions to avoid "transgenderism", among other terms), but that's more about how to talk about trans people than how to talk about views related to trans people.

As they also note, "transsexual" / "transsexuality" is also an older term that many trans people reject.

---

As for why accepting the existence of trans people is controversial:

#### "Humans are made perfectly"

If you believe that humans are made perfectly, the idea that someone could require (gender-affirming) surgery because of how they were born could be an uncomfortable truth to swallow.

I mean, there are countless medical conditions someone can be born with that requires surgery to fix, and people don't have a problem with most of those. Maybe it's just harder to pretend that those don't exist.

#### "There is only man and woman"

Because their religion says so, or because of biology they learnt in primary school, people have latched onto the idea that man and woman are strictly defined categories, that those are purely defined by biology and there's no other determining factor to gender (even though most such people will also say that men and women think differently, which makes it odd for them to be so adamant that there cannot exist someone with the body of a man who thinks like a woman - I mean, you don't think with your genitals, generally speaking).

#### "Ick!"

Some people find the idea of trans people to be "icky", so it's just more convenient for them to pretend that such people don't exist, or to want to ban them from bathrooms or other spaces, so they never have to see them.

By the same logic, we could ban people from bathrooms based on their weight, race, etc. Which is to say it's a terrible reason.

#### "It's different!"

People are generally resistant to changing what they believe and accepting that they were wrong or believed something false.

#### "If we accept trans people, the universe will explode!"

Some people like to make vague apocalyptic claims about the downfall of society and there's some impending war and literally the only thing that would allow us to win it would be Christian values (for some generally very poorly defined reasons). A prominent recent example is Ayaan Hirsi Ali's [conversion](https://youtu.be/Z7UKHUUcWoo) [to](https://youtu.be/Kmx1pE2rvKU) ["Christianity"](https://youtu.be/mdW3snShA9k) (for which her given reasons are purely political and has nothing to do with whether it's actually true). ... and she did explicitly talk about an actual impending war, in case you're wondering.

The above isn't explicitly about trans people, but such people also commonly say that such values exclude LGBT people (not that this is a universal Christian view).

#### "Traditional" family values

Related to the above, people also proclaim the importance of ["traditional"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_tradition) family values, that excludes LGBT people, and say children need both a masculine father and a feminine mother to be well-adjusted. But this is largely just asserted without evidence, it's an illogical reason to ban relationships or medical treatments, and it's equally applicable to single parenthood, but you don't tend to hear them complaining about that.

They'll also that "traditional" families are prescribed by their religion, or that it's best for the people involved, but that second one is a highly doubtful claim that's contrary to pretty much every piece of evidence we have.

---

As for feminism, people can also object due to "traditional" family values and gender roles. Beyond that, the biggest objection is probably:

#### "Society is perfect"

People don't really want to accept that there's systemic problems in society. That would mean that even if everyone treats each other well, some people would still end up being disadvantaged. That even if someone works really hard, they may still not achieve success. It's far easier to just put the blame on individuals: if someone is treated unfairly, you could just say it's because of what a "bad" person did, or that their treatment wasn't unfair.

---

All of the above is just about the anti-feminism anti-trans side. The reason why the pro side is pushing back is simple:

#### People's well-being and lives are at stake.

When people misrepresent facts or present bad anti-trans or anti-feminist arguments, that could do significant damage to the lives of real people in the real world. If ever there is a reason to get upset over something, that would be it.

Someone could also understandably be upset when you tell them what they're feeling isn't valid, they aren't feeling what they're feeling, or that you understand what they're feeling better than they do (at least if you aren't their psychologist, citing diagnoses in line with the consensus of the scientific community... but that's generally pro-trans, not anti-trans).

Comment: Good answer. However, some complications happen when traditional feminists reject trans women, or consider them as men in disguise.

Comment: @Olivier5 I think "archaic" is a better adjective than "traditional" for anti-trans feminists. There isn't much traditional in feminism about rejecting trans identities. Although they could be viewed as traditional in the sense that society has a tradition of discrimination and oppression.

Comment: "*As for why accepting the existence of trans people is controversial:*"  There is no more controversy around acknowledging and accepting the "existence" of transgender people as there is around the existence of any other societal group.  Agreeing with and approving of related policies are different than simply acknowledging the existence of people who identify as such.

Comment: @MichaelHall "accepting the existence of trans people" doesn't mean "accepting the existence of people who describe themselves as trans", it means "accepting the existence of people whose gender doesn't match their assigned sex at birth". "Tall people" isn't people who describe themselves as tall, it's people who *are* tall.

Comment: @NotThatGuy, I don't really understand your point.  You are offering a couple possible definitions around my phrase, but I didn't specify one over the other...  (and what does "assigned sex at birth" mean?  Sex has nothing to do with gender, right?)

Comment: @MichaelHall I was pointing out that anti-trans people don't accept the existence of trans people. You certainly have the ability to make up your own definition of "trans people" if you want, such that they do technically accept their existence, but (a) you're disagreeing with something I wrote in my answer, so it would be disingenuous and pointlessly creating conflict to interpret that with a different definition from what I intended (after I clarified), and (b) a different definition would be contrary to how those words are commonly understood, which would create unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @MichaelHall You can't tell the gender of a baby that's just been born when they haven't even figured out basic bodily functions, never mind having any level of gender expression or ability to communicate concept concepts in their head (if there is even complex concepts in their head). So yes, babies are classified based on sex. And sex has a lot to do with gender, the 2 just aren't inseparable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149975/discussion-between-michael-hall-and-notthatguy).

Comment: I appreciate that you wrote a response to this question rather than a vote-to-close.  I mean, to be clear, I find a lot of these ideas too shallow, reflecting little consideration, and so I can't say that I agree.  But.. progress is a beautiful thing.

Comment: To pull just one thread:  The source talking about "_transgenderism_" apparently misunderstands the term (since their definition seems a bit silly -- the way they discuss it, they seem to think it refers to the "_condition_" of _being_ trans rather than the ideological framework that supports the notion of genders that can exist in a trans-configuration).  Of course, [they're a political-action group](https://glaad.org/about/) with a specific political cause -- they are not an academic/scholarly source and don't claim to be.

Comment: @Nat Pro-trans people take a position on the factual issue of whether trans people exist. To say that's an ideology (which people often do) would be like saying believing the Earth is a globe is an ideology. If you want to use that word that way, I can't stop you, but that's not how it's commonly understood. Ideology means ideals that go beyond facts, and the ideals of trans activism is of equality and compassion. To disagree with equality and compassion would make you *evil*. But most people who disagree (yourself seemingly included) disagree on the factual aspect, not the ideological one.

Comment: Yeah, to me this is all religious nonsense and I'd prefer to be an atheist.  By which I mean, I reject not only this sort of ideology, but also binary-gender ideology too -- it's not the number of genders or their assignment that's the issue, but rather folks extending empirical-things like biological-sex to spirituality.  Of course, I'm all too happy to acknowledge folks' right to identify however they like, including in whatever spiritual/religious terms they care for.

Comment: @Nat Being trans is who you are, not how you identify, so you've seemingly (again) just admitted that you disagree on the factual aspect (whether someone can "be" trans), not the ideological one. And much like a reply you left to me elsewhere, you seem to just be attacking my character instead of actually offering any sort of rebuttal to the case I made. Calling it "religious nonsense" provides no insight into what's wrong with what I said. One has to wonder whether you're merely disinterested in this discussion, or whether you're *unable* to offer a rebuttal.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Of course people can be trans, just like people can be [Libra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libra_(astrology)) or American or Republican or vegetarian or.. well, whatever other labels.  Why are you asking about that?

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Actually, let me ask you: can people "_be_" Libra?  (In the sense of "_being_" trans, as you posed above.)  Note that my reason for asking this is to try to figure out what you were trying to say with an analogy.

Comment: @Nat Someone can be "Libra" in the sense that they were, factually speaking, born between the 54th of August and the -7th of November, or whatever dates, and someone can believe, factually speaking, that that corresponds to personality traits (even if that's highly dubious), and someone can factually speaking hold those beliefs. None of those are ideologies. It's an ideology if you then say that Libras should be banned from bathrooms or whatever. Do you believe, factually speaking, that men and women inherently think differently, and someone can exist who has a male body but thinks as a woman?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149985/discussion-between-nat-and-notthatguy).

Answer (score -2):

Feminism and transsexuality should not be controversial in a philosophical context. They obviously exist within a political background. So questions about these subjects here should be answered in a philosophical context, taking into account the political background. But particular political views should not be promoted, nor should anyone be abused. Since no one else answered my final question, yes, philosophy is male-dominated and that is part of the problem here.

Comment: I think if an argument on transgender issues lends itself to certain political views - most, if not all arguments on transgender issues do I imagine - then there is no escaping promoting (implicitly or otherwise) those political values. For example, by virtue of arguing for the equality of rights for transgender people, or by affirming the issues of transgender people, you will be endorsing a side of the political spectrum that agrees and condemning the side that doesn't. Agree on no abuse, but disagree on 'should not to be promoted'. It's necessary with the territory here.

Comment: I won't desist from my point. Things like the correct interpretation of QM or "cogito ergo sum" are considered controversial in philosophy. But feminism and gender should not be controversial? Why? Is it a problem if certain things are controversial or political? To me, that makes them interesting.